# Do or does: “Stative verbs show a state of being that does/do...”

Tags: grammatical-number

I read the sentence 'Stative verbs show a state of being that does not show qualities of change' on [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/present-continuous/).

I'd expected **do** instead of **does**, in the sentence. But by this, my understanding is that, the intended subject of a sentence is solely depended on the third person singular present. So if I wanted to make **stative verbs** the subject of the sentence, then I should use **do**?

Answer (score 2):

I've marked the finite verbs below and their subjects:

> **Stative verbs *show*** a state of being that does not show qualities of change.
>
> Stative verbs show **a state of being** that ***does* not show** qualities of change.

The verb "show" belongs to the subject "stative verbs" and is third person plural.

Comment: Okay, but what about do and does?

Comment: @NoamanAli "a state of being that do ..." is not grammatical.

Comment: Can you elucidate on why it isn't grammatical? Remove 'show a state of being that' from the sentence and tell if if that's still grammatical.

Comment: 1. Stative verbs **show** a state of being. 2. That state of being **does** not show qualities of change. 3. Stative verbs **do** not show qualities of change. You need to match the right verb with the right subject in each clause. One sentence can have multiple clauses.